# How can I query subtraction of two values grouped by certain categories based on timestamp min max on big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Hi I have a table like this ( just an example)

| Dashboarding Category | timestamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PV ENERGY | 11/03/2022 | 113.957348 |
| BATTERY ENERGY | 11/03/2022 | 140.5875153 |
| HEAT ENERGY | 11/03/2022 | 276.9997795 |
| TOTAL ENERGY | 11/03/2022 | 487.9871685 |
| PV ENERGY | 14/03/2022 | 534.6937951 |
| BATTERY ENERGY | 14/03/2022 | 625.9614076 |
| HEAT ENERGY | 14/03/2022 | 669.2673149 |
| TOTAL ENERGY | 14/03/2022 | 1175.157762 |
| PV ENERGY | 19/03/2022 | 1352.12033 |
| BATTERY ENERGY | 19/03/2022 | 1747.298151 |
| HEAT ENERGY | 19/03/2022 | 1891.235057 |
| TOTAL ENERGY | 19/03/2022 | 1909.890893 |
| PV ENERGY | 20/03/2022 | 2118.666904 |
| BATTERY ENERGY | 20/03/2022 | 2335.954084 |
| HEAT ENERGY | 20/03/2022 | 2542.706342 |
| TOTAL ENERGY | 20/03/2022 | 2675.744966 |
| PV ENERGY | 21/03/2022 | 3513.539046 |
| BATTERY ENERGY | 21/03/2022 | 4464.32658 |
| HEAT ENERGY | 21/03/2022 | 4469.372355 |
| TOTAL ENERGY | 21/03/2022 | 4650.514689 |

And this is the result I want based on the min and maximum timestamp in the entire table and extracting the corresponding values by dashboarding category.The query result expected is below

| Dashboarding Category | value(t_min) | value(t_max) | max-min_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PV ENERGY | 113.957348 | 3513.539046 | 3399.581698 |
| BATTERY ENERGY | 140.5875153 | 4464.32658 | 4323.739064 |
| HEAT ENERGY | 276.9997795 | 4469.372355 | 4192.372575 |
| TOTAL ENERGY | 487.9871685 | 4650.514689 | 4162.52752 |

How can I achieve this in big query?

Thanks!

Comment: Should this be group by?   
Select category, min(value), max(value),  max(value) - min(value) as difference
group by category

Comment: sure I can change the category if that would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select *, value_t_max - value_t_min as max_minus_min_value
from (
  select DashboardingCategory, 
    array_agg(value order by timestamp limit 1)[offset(0)] as value_t_min,
    array_agg(value order by timestamp desc limit 1)[offset(0)] as value_t_max,
  from  your_table
  group by DashboardingCategory
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This worked as well! I am thinking what will happen if i add an external time filter on it, will it be able to calculate the min and max for that particular selection?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Bigquery, but I think it supports common table expressions like most other database types. The CTEs calculate and use a value referenced later in the query. This works, where you are using those CTEs to get the min and max values, and the bottom brings it altogether.

```
    with min_max_time as (
     select category, min(dt) as min_date, max(dt) as max_date
     from energy
     group by category
    ),
    min_value as (
     select e.category, e.evalue
     from energy e
     join min_max_time mmt
       on e.category = mmt.category
      and e.dt = mmt.min_date
    ), 
    max_value as (
     select e.category, e.evalue
     from energy e
     join min_max_time mmt
       on e.category = mmt.category
      and e.dt = mmt.max_date
    )
    select distinct e.category,
     minv.evalue as value_t_min, 
     maxv.evalue as value_t_max, 
     maxv.evalue - minv.evalue as max_minus_min_value
    from energy e
    join min_value minv
      on e.category = minv.category
    join max_value maxv
      on e.category = maxv.category
```

Db-fiddle found [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gumzrpgoVkELjWF21jRSq2/0).

**EDIT**
Based on your comment, here's another solution that determines the min and max by Category and Building:

```
    with min_max_time as (
     select category, building, min(dt) as min_date, max(dt) as max_date
     from energy
     group by category, building
    ) ,
    min_value as (
    select e.category, e.building, e.evalue
    from energy e
    join min_max_time mmt
      on e.category = mmt.category
     and e.dt = mmt.min_date
     and e.building = mmt.building
    ), 
    max_value as (
    select e.category, e.building, e.evalue
    from energy e
    join min_max_time mmt
      on e.category = mmt.category
     and e.dt = mmt.max_date
     and e.building = mmt.building
    )
    select distinct e.category, 
    e.building, 
    minv.evalue as value_t_min, 
    maxv.evalue as value_t_max, 
    maxv.evalue - minv.evalue as max_minus_min_value
    from energy e
    join min_value minv
      on e.category = minv.category
     and e.building = minv.building
    join max_value maxv
      on e.category = maxv.category
     and e.building = maxv.building
```

The db-fiddle is found [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/raMmBurP7ZKKWj6LWPcMF1/0), and the output looks like this:

```
    category        building    value_t_min     value_t_max     max_minus_min_value
    BATTERY ENERGY  house       140.5875153     4464.32658      4323.7390647
    BATTERY ENERGY  shed        40.5875153      464.32658       423.7390647
    HEAT ENERGY     house       276.9997795     4469.372355     4192.3725755
    HEAT ENERGY     shed        76.9997795      469.372355      392.3725755
    PV ENERGY       house       113.957348      3513.539046     3399.581698
    PV ENERGY       shed        13.957348       513.539046      499.581698
    TOTAL ENERGY    house       487.9871685     4650.514689     4162.5275205
    TOTAL ENERGY    shed        87.9871685      650.514689      562.5275205
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much! This worked on my unioned table! thank you! however there is a potential thing that I have missed !What if I have to group it by two things , "category" and lets say "House" ? I tried to modify the code to include that but it returns more results than it should. It does not seem to be distinct

Comment: Added another version, one that groups by category and building.

Comment: Actually this is exactly how I modified, but for your table you are getting unique row, for mine I am getting the same category multiple times for the  same building

Comment: Check all the joins in the CTEs and the main query, and make sure you're using "select distinct" in the main query.

Comment: Hi I copied your code ditto and just replaced the energy table with mine! Still getting duplicates!